# How to get the name of MatchAllFilters and other filters that have been created? What changes to the interface need to be made?

Tags: java, arraylist, filter, interface, filtering

What changes do I need to make for the "all the Filter classes"?  For the MatchAllFilter class, a getName method should return a String of all the Filter names in its ArrayList which I don't know how to do. I also was wondering how would I use the getName method in filter like depth?

```
public interface Filter { 
   public String getName();
   public  boolean satisfies(QuakeEntry qe);
}


public class DepthFilter implements Filter {
    private double depthMin;
    private double depthMax;
    private String fName;

    public DepthFilter(double min, double max, String name) {
        depthMin = min;
        depthMax = max;
        fName = name;

    }

    public boolean satisfies(QuakeEntry qe) {
        if (qe.getDepth() >= depthMin && qe.getDepth() <= depthMax) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}

public class MatchAllFilter implements Filter {
    private ArrayList<Filter> filters;
    private String fName;

    public MatchAllFilter() {
        filters = new ArrayList<Filter>();

    }

public void addFilter(Filter f){
    filters.add(f);

    public boolean satisfies(QuakeEntry qe) {
        for (Filter f : filters) {
            if (!f.satisfies(qe)) { // any of the filters criteria failed, then exit
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @shmosel I am trying to learn how to code from books and MOOCs. I literally have no one except StackOverflow to ask for help. My code already works as is but the getName() part is throwing everything off .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About Interfaces in Java:**

Interfaces are about defining a contract for what a class can do, without saying anything about how the class will do it. The contract is fulfilled by implementing the interface methods in a class.

- An interface has abstract methods and constants.
- A class implements an interface - the keyword implements is used.
- A class can implement more than one interface.

**From the post's code samples:**

The interface `Filter` has two *abstract* methods: `getName` and `satisfies`. The implementing class *must* implement both the abstract methods (and can define other methods). Implementing the abstract method involves providing the method body; e.g.:

```
public String getName() {
    return fName;
}
```

Using interfaces is also considered as a type of inheritance; generally, inheritance in Java is about extending a class. The above notes refers to pre-Java 8 and as of Java SE 8 interfaces can have *default* and *static* methods (optionally).

**Strings and concatenation:**

> Q. For the MatchAllFilter class, a getName method should return a
>   String of all the Filter names in its ArrayList which I don't know how
>   to do.

As I have mentioned above the `getName` method must be implemented. How to make a string of all elements in an `ArrayList`? One can get each name and concatenate then together. Obviously, this involves `String` concatenation - here is some sample code for that:

```
String s1 = "one";
String s2 = "two";
String concatenatedString = s1 + " * " + s2;
System.out.println(concatenatedString); // This prints: one * two
```

Note that strings can also be concatenated using the [String class's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) `concat` method.

**Concatenate all elements in an ArrayList collection:**

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("one"); list.add("two"); list.add("three"); // Make a list of 3 elements
String allStrings = ""; // This will have all the elements of the collection
// Iterate the list collection and get each element and concatenate
for (String ele : list) {
    allStrings = allStrings + ele;
}
System.out.println(allStrings); // This prints: onetwothree
```

Also, one can print an `ArrayList`s contents like this (generally useful in seeing all elements):

```
System.out.println(list); // This prints: [one, two, three]
```

Answer (score 1):

Each one of your filters `implements Filter` right?

The interface `Filter` has a `getName()` that you had to implement on each class.

Perhaps each filter needs a way in their constructor for you to pass a `String name` right?

Then it should be easy to get the name of any filter by using `getName()`

Example:

```
DepthFilter depthFilter = new DepthFilter(1.5, 5.5, "myOwnFilter");
String name = depthFilter.getName();
```

Comment: Would I put the constructor in `public String getName(){
        return fName;
    
    }` Do I need a private variable still?

Comment: See how DepthFilter's constructor has a `name` argument that is saved into `fname`? You probably have to do the same with `MatchAllFilter`

Comment: Because I add  `public string getName()` to the interface I need to add `public string getName()`to every filter and I need to return the name there. That's what I am specifically struggling with.

Comment: Everywhere you use the Interface.

Comment: `public class DepthFilter implements Filter {
    private double depthMin;
    private double depthMax;
    private String fName;

    public DepthFilter(double min, double max, String name) {
        depthMin = min;
        depthMax = max;
        fName = name;

    }` what would I add here specifically.